# Can I live view my Nikon D3200 via laptop/ tablet etc?

Tags: nikon, live-view, self-portrait

I am wanting to take self portraits using my Nikon D3200 and was wondering is there a way I can stream the live view through a laptop, tablet or some other screen?

I want to have the screen facing me so I can see what the picture will look like before I capture it so it's not a case of clicking and hoping.

I have an AV out (from camera) to USB lead and also an AV out (from camera) to the yellow and white lead

Hope that makes sense

Thanks

Comment: Here is a relevant question with answers that might be helpful for you as well: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/36130/9161

Comment: Slightly different model (D3100, the predecessor to the D3200), but the exact same issue and answer. http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/36130/15871

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Windows you could try out [DigiCamControl](http://digicamcontrol.com) <sup>(I'm not affiliated)</sup>. They list the [Nikon D3200](http://digicamcontrol.com/supported_cameras/d3200) as partially supported. Live view works, however, [you can't use manual focus in live view and can't set the focus area.](http://digicamcontrol.com/comment/991#comment-991)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Sofortblid would work with your camera and provide the features you need if you are on mac. (Other answer is windows only.)

http://www.sofortbildapp.com