# Nikon D3200 video tethering software?

Tags: remote, tethering, nikon-d3200, hd-video

With Canon's EOS Utility software, you can connect your Canon DSLR to a laptop via HDMI and:

- control focus and zoom (if you have autofocus lenses),
- start and stop video recording,
- white balance,
- see RGB histograms

I can't find any mention of similar software for Nikon.  I have found plenty of tethering software, but they do not use HDMI and are not intended for video.

Essentially, I am looking to duplicate the function of this item using a laptop:

https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/blackmagicvideoassist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to replicate Nikon D3100 live view on my laptop screen?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/36130/is-there-a-way-to-replicate-nikon-d3100-live-view-on-my-laptop-screen)

Comment: The answers to the linked possible duplicate question explain that the D3x00 series cameras are not supported by Nikon's SDK.

Comment: Re: Canon DSLRs and what can be controlled via tethering. Focus - yes (ALL EF and EF-S lenses have AF. Every single one. The four TS-E lenses and the MP-E 1-5X macro are the only EOS lenses that don't have an AF motor). Zoom - no (No EOS lenses have camera controllable zoom. Not a single one.).

Comment: @charlzm There's a reason everyone using this type of external monitor/recorder is using Canon and not Nikon cameras...

Comment: Which is also pretty much the same reason the device you linked runs on the same battery that powers the Canon 5DII, 5DIII, 7D, 7D II, etc.

Answer (score 2):

EOS Utility use USB connection not HDMI to control canon cameras. There are software for Nikon with same features [digiCamControl](http://digicamcontrol.com/) or [dslrdashboard](http://dslrdashboard.info/) but you can't trigger video capture for D3200 using a software and USB connection.